# R - Add column to a first data.frame based on another data.frame sharing a similar column but with a different length

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have a first data.frame `d1` that contains 2 number (A and B) for each organism.

```
Organism1 <- c("name1", "name3", "name5") 
Number1 <- c("numberA1", "numberA3", "numberA5") 
Number2 <- c("numberB1", "numberB3", "numberB5") 
d1 <- data.frame(Organism1, Number1, Number2)
d1
```

I have a second data.frame `d2` that contains the status of each organism

```
Organism2 = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6")
Status = c("Bad", "Good", "Neutral", "Good", "Good", "Bad")
d2 = data.frame(Organism2, Status)
d2
```

And I'd like to 'merge' these 2 data.frame to obtain a third one called `d3` that corresponds to `d1` + the `Status` column

```
Organism3 = c("name1", "name3", "name5") 
Number1 = c("numberA1", "numberA3", "numberA5") 
Number2 = c("numberB1", "numberB3", "numberB5") 
Status3 = c("Bad", "Neutral", "Good")
d3 = data.frame(Organism1, Number1, Number2, Status3) 
d3
```

The idea is just to add the status column to each organism in `d1`. 
For each `d1` organism that is not in `d2` just put `NA` in `d3`

I looked at the `merge` function but did not succeed to obtain what I want.

Comment: It's moot now, but you should show what you tried with `merge`. That will help us understand where your confusion is and explain the parts you don't understand rather than just showing a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `merge` you obtain this output:

```
merge(d1,d2,by.x="Organism1",by.y="Organism2", all.x=T)
  Organism1  Number1  Number2  Status
1     name1 numberA1 numberB1     Bad
2     name3 numberA3 numberB3 Neutral
3     name5 numberA5 numberB5    Good
```

But in your desired output `d3` you have differents values in `Status`, what's your logic?

Comment: My mistake, just edited my post. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`full_join()` in the `dplyr` library is made for this:

```
d1 %>%
  full_join(d2, by = c("Organism1" = "Organism2"))
```

`left_join()` returns something similar but with only the rows that appear in `d1`.